# Bootstrap row (changing position of image)

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4

I need to pull a picture with a sign 1 to the top of a red field. I can't change position in bootstrap. Whenever I tried to do that by CSS it fit. But after changing the page size it totally messes. is there any way to do that by bootstrap?

[image]

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row position-relative">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="a.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="b.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="c.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="d.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="e.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="f.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="g.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="i.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="j.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="k.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="l.jpg" alt=""></div>
            l-6 px-0"><img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You need flow grid system for aligment of image and resposive also  in bootstrap

URL:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/